# How do I reopen programs using CMD from a list or variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

I have a section of code;

```
:check
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('"wmic process get description, commandline /format:list"') do (
  if "%%A"=="CommandLine" (
    set "cmd=%%B"
  ) else if "%%A"=="Description" (
    set "desc=%%B"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "desc=!desc:~0,-1!"
    set "cmd=!cmd:~0,-1!"
    if /i !desc! == %1         (
      echo !cmd! >>C:\test.txt
    )
    endlocal
  )
)
goto:eof
```

Which pretty much works (this is actually a function called from withing a batch file e.g

```
call:check processname1.exe
call:check processname2.exe
call:check processname3.exe
etc...
```

What I'd like to do (if possible), is, insead of echoing to a file, I'd like to be able to create 2 variables. something like;

```
processname1.exe processname3.exe   <-- (for each process 'checked' if it IS running, append its name to this variable)
commandlinepath1 commandlinepath2   <-- (for each process 'checked' if it IS running, append its path to this variable)
```

If this is possible, and I can then call on these variable later in my script, I'd like to be able to tskill the running processes (easy enough if the variables above can be made), then later on, RE-OPEN these processes (using and command line parameter that were in the original path.  This is where I'm lost.

My code above (writing to a file). will give results like;

```
"C:\somefolder\someexe.exe" -some_parameter
"C:\some therfolder\someotherexe.exe"
"C:\another older\anotherexe.exe" param1 param2
```

But What I need to do, is take each line of this file (or variable if possible), and run them (if I copy each line into the RUN command of windows, it works, but doing it through CMD it doesn't).

I've tried using a for loop to open the files, and it does, except the script waits for the process to finish beford continuing (and these process won't end, since they are applications).  If I try to use START ..  then it loads a new CMD window??

What I need to do (in case there is a better option) is

- for a pre-determined set of processes, check to see if they are running
- kill the ones that are (if they are not, fine ignore it)
- delete some files (I can do this, the reason for killin the processes is they hold the files open, preventing deletion)
- Re-open all the programs that were originally running

Thanks..

Comment: If the EXE file is a console program (text-based), `START` would open a new window. If the EXE file is a GUI program, `START` won't open a new window. Forcing to use `/B` parameter without waiting a console program to finish (without `/WAIT`) would cause input conflict since both CMD and the program is run in the same window and any input will be given to both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but since you already use wmic, maybe using its built in capabilities (query, start & stop) would make your goal easier to achieve?

I come up with the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%C in (notepad.exe) do (
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%F in ('wmic process where description^="%%C" get commandline /format:list') do (
    REM required to normalize unicode output from WMIC 
    set commandline=%%F
    REM '\=\\' required as wmic treats \ as escape char in query
    call wmic process where commandline='%%commandline:\=\\%%' terminate

    REM do your work here

    call wmic process call create '%%commandline%%'

    )
)
```

What it does: 
First `for` supplies process names. In my example, it simply is `notepad.exe`, but you could call with a list: `for (process1 process2 process3)`, or replace it with `for /f` to supply values from file. If you want to use quoted names, you would have to remove quote from next line (`description^="%%C"`).
Second `for` does real work: it gets a list of all processes matching description and sequentially stops and starts each of them.

To try it, simply put it in a `batfile.bat`, open notepad(s) and execute.
Note: if you open notepad with a file, either specify an absolute path, or do it via explorer (double click). The issue here is of current directory - which you could also stumble upon if any of your processes does reference relative paths (unlikely, but not impossible)

**Last but not least** - doing that in powershell would be the easiest, shortest and most reliable.